# EJB 3.0 timer not working in weblogic cluster

Tags: oracle, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

Have an issue with EJB 3.0 Timer in a weblogic (10.x) 2 node cluster environment.
The time should fire or timeout every 1 minute (pre-configured), only from one node of the cluster.

But when the timer is deployed in 2 node cluster, it is not getting fired from any node.

**Steps followed :**

1) Created a EJB 3.0 project with a stateless session bean having timer configured.
Created a servlet with loadonstartup set to 1, which triggers EJB createTimer method.
Enabled the clustered EJB timer service, set the timer-implementation element in the weblogic-ejb-jar.xml to clustered

```
   <timer-implementation>Clustered</timer-implementation>
```

2) HA database pointed to Oracle Db in which WEBLOGIC_TIMERS and ACTIVE table are created.

3) JDBC data source that is mapped to the HA database using the  element in the config.xml file.

4) Leasing service defined by JDBC data source using  element in the config.xml.

**weblogic-ejb-jar.xml descriptor file:**

```
<weblogic-ejb-jar>
<weblogic-enterprise-bean>
<ejb-name>ClusteredSessionEJB</ejb-name>
<stateless-session-descriptor>
  <pool>
    <max-beans-in-free-pool>1</max-beans-in-free-pool>
    <initial-beans-in-free-pool>1</initial-beans-in-free-pool>
  </pool>
  <stateless-clustering>
    <home-is-clusterable>true</home-is-clusterable>
    <home-load-algorithm>round-robin</home-load-algorithm>
    <stateless-bean-is-clusterable>true</stateless-bean-is-clusterable>
    <stateless-bean-load-algorithm>round-robin</stateless-bean-load-algorithm>
  </stateless-clustering>

</stateless-session-descriptor>
</weblogic-enterprise-bean>
<timer-implementation>Clustered</timer-implementation>
</weblogic-ejb-jar>
```

**EJB Code :**

```
@Stateless(name = "ClusteredSessionEJB", mappedName = "TimerClusterApp-Model-   ClusteredSessionEJB")
public class ClusteredSessionEJBBean implements ClusteredSessionEJB {

@Resource
   TimerService mdsCacheUpdateTimer;

@Timeout
public void scheduleJob(final Timer timerObj) {
   LOGGER.info("scheduleJob fired in ClusteredSessionEJBBean"); 
 }

 public void createTimer() {

     LOGGER.setLevel(Level.INFO);
     LOGGER.info("creating timer in ClusteredSessionEJBBean"); 
     mdsCacheUpdateTimer.createTimer(60000, 60000, "ClusteredSessionEJBBean-Timer");

 }
}
```

Comment: So you've followed something similar to this https://blogs.oracle.com/muraliveligeti/entry/ejb_timer_ejb ? Might need to post your entire weblogic-ejb-jar.xml and code

Comment: thanks! I have edit my question with the code and DD

Comment: Did you solve this?? I have the same problem